# Getting object value from a string

Tags: php, string, variables, metaprogramming

I've got a problem to share with you all. The thing is, I would like to extract the value of a complex object having its name stored in a string variable.

As you may know, you can do the following:

```
$foo = 'Hello World';

$var = 'foo';

echo var_dump($$var); // Output: string(11) "Hello World"
```

The problem comes when you try to do:

```
$data = new stdClass();

$data->param["foo"]["bar"] = 'Hello World';

$var = 'data->param["foo"]["bar"]';

echo var_dump($$var); // Output: NULL
```

I can imagine why the parser can't do this. The only workaround that I can think of is to split $var into smaller chunks ('->', '[', ']', ...) and evaluate it step by step.

Does anyone know a more elegant solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: i don't think its possible to use elements like -> or [ in that manner ...

Comment: "Variable variables" just have a variable variable name. They are not variable expressions. And sorry, there is no nicer workaround. But can you elaborate on your use case anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `data->param["foo"]["bar"]` is not a variable name, that's why you can't use it in `$$var`.

You are better off using `eval()` in this case, something like this

```
$var = 'return $data->param["foo"]["bar"];';
var_dump(eval($var));
```

And yeah, you don't need to `echo var_dump`, just `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it by doing the following:

```
<?php

$data = new stdClass();

$data->param["foo"]["bar"] = 'Hello World';

$var = 'data->param["foo"]["bar"]';

$value = eval('return $'.$var.';');

var_dump($value);
```

Comment: It seems that your answer is generally the same as the answer by *German Rumm*. If you don't mind, please accept that answer by clicking the tick next to the post. Also, you don't really need the `return` in the `eval` string.

Comment: well i generally never advice using eval @Delan Azabani has a Point

Comment: That's true, Hannes, `eval` has a lot of small problems that can become big problems, as well as being inefficient, and should be avoided where there's a better alternative. I only know basic PHP so I don't really have an answer to contribute.

Comment: @Delan Azabani, it doesn't seem to work without return (`var_dump()` shows `NULL`), that's why I added it.